# Amazon Marketplace API - wsdl

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, wsdl

I have been around the web a lot in the past day and was wondering does Amazon API have a .wsdl file? Im struggling to understand how I talk to their web service.

I've downloaded https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/180-1400280-4320051?ie=UTF8&section=feeds&group=bde&version=latest

And have also signed up for MWS. As well as found this wsdl file but this seems to relate to something else as I cant find reference to anything I found related to MWS such as OperationType. http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

However at no point does it seem to reference a wsdl file.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All feed information can be found:

**PRODUCTS**

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf

**ORDERS**

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/2011-01-01/MWSOrdersApiReference.*V361506650*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/2011-01-01/MWSOrdersApiReference._V361506650_.pdf)

**Basically you do the following:**

1. Create your XML document (if required)
2. Create a webrequest - making
   sure the query string contains all the elements required and nothing
   more or less (this is very important), the  order of these is also
   important. Use:
   https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html to work out
   which elements are required
3. Sign the request
4. Receive a response.

Thanks,

Clare

Comment: Clare, how did you obtain those links?  Thought a whole roundabout way I got to the same place, but the xsd files are dated 2012.  Is there a way to see if they have been updated, because when I look at templates for product types there are missing properties/classes.

This is a vexing issue.